# Determinar con JavaScript si un número es simétrico

Tags: javascript, variables, bucles

Tengo este ejercicio:

> la funcion `llamada` recibe como argumento un número entero. Esta
> devuelve true o false dependiendo de si el número es simétrico o no.
> Un número es simétrico cuando es igual a su reverso.

Yo convertí el número que me dan como argumento en `string`, lo recorrí con un ciclo `for` de atrás para adelante y fui guardando todo en un nuevo string para luego comparar si eran iguales, y de ser así significaba que era simétrico, ¡según yo! Pero no me aprueba el ejercicio.

Acá les dejo el código de lo que hice.
Siendo NUM el argumento que me dieron:

```
var numToString = num.ToString()
var numAlReves = '';
for (let i = numToString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   numAlReves = numAlReves + numToString[i];
};
if (numAlReves === numToString) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Una forma de lograr lo que te propones es usando el método [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) del tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

La idea es convertir el número original en cadena, luego crear un `Array` con los datos de dicha cadena e invertir sus valores, luego volver a convertir el `Array` invertido en una cadena y comparar con la cadena original.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let numeros = [
  127,       // false
  121,       // true
  123498,    // false
  985,       // false
  876545678, // true
  11         // true
];

const isReversible = (num) => {
  let original = num.toString();
  let reversed = original.split('').reverse().join('');
  return original === reversed;
}

numeros.forEach(num => {
  console.log(num , " esReversible?", isReversible(num));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo unico que javascript no es como java para pasarlo a String el numero debes de utilizar el constructor String(), entonces te quedaria algo asi:

```
 var numToString = String(num);
  var numAlReves = "";
  for (let i = numToString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    numAlReves = numAlReves + numToString[i];
  }
  if (numAlReves === numToString) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Todos los valores numéricos en Javascript (de hecho todos los Objetos) disponen del método [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) para obtener la representación en cadena del número. Saludos

Comment: completando lo dicho por @MauricioContreras;  en Javascript  todo valor primitivo tambien es un objeto, Javascript hace la envoltura de objeto(Wrapper Object), por ello tienes acceso a los metodos .toString()  como por ejemplo